# How to use other table JSON data in select query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am using postgres and have 2 tables, `deviceTble` has the following columns: `deviceName`, `device_id`, `type`, `deviceOwnerPerson_id`, `deviceAccessPerson_id`.

The other table is `Person_kv` and has 2 columns `id`,`data` (containing person info but in JSON format).

I want to a select query from deviceTble and want to use first_name and last_name of a person which are in Person_kv table by given of deviceOwnerPersonId and deviceAccessPersonId.

Here is what I have to get data from person_kv table to get data in tabular form:

```
select data :: json ->> 'id' as id
  , data :: json ->> 'name' as first_name
  , data :: json ->> 'surename' as last_name
from Person_kv
```

and expected deviceTble query:

```
select deviceName,device_id,type from deviceTble
```

I am confused either I use WITH clause on person_kv query and then join here or one by one on deviceOwnerPerson_id and deviceAccessPerson_id OR is there any other way as well by using inner query

Can someone tell me how I can get required result?

Comment: You want a join between those tables. [Joins Between Tables in the Postgres tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from you description you can just join em:

```
select deviceName,device_id,type, p.data:: json ->>'name' , p.data:: json ->>'surname' 
from deviceTble d
join Person_kv  p on p.data:: json ->>'id' = deviceOwnerPerson_id::text OR p.data:: json ->>'id' = deviceAccessPerson_id::text
```

Comment: Perfect solution. I was thinking of using join by making With clause on both statement.